# Assembly replacing constant with a register value

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, neon

I'm not an expert with assembly so this may be simple.

If I have an instruction that expects a constant value as a parameter like so:

```
VQSHRN.U32 d0,q0,#16
```

How can I replace `#16` with a value in a register, eg `r0`?  This instruction may even allow you to do so, but I haven't found docs on that capability.  Is there a normal method of doing this?

In case this matters, I'm writing ARMv7 assembly and putting it inline with c++ code.  Thanks.

Comment: See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0348a/BABDFGBJ.html

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the link.  I'm trying to do the above instruction except using a shift held in a register.  I want to keep it as few instructions as possible.  Any tips?  I basically need a Vector rounding narrowing saturating shift right by value in register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael pointed out, `VQRSHL` is the appropriate shift-by-register instruction here - fortunately, right happens to be negative left. I'd use a `VDUP` to turn `r0` into an appropriate vector of shift values first, and a `VQMOVN` afterwards for the narrowing. All of these are available as intrinsics to help keep the nastiness of inline assembly at bay, something like this:

```
vshift = vdupq_n_s32(-shift);
result = vqmovn_u32(vqrshlq_u32(data, vshift));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the particular instructions.  This should work.  FYI the C code I'm trying to duplicate is #define CV_DESCALE(x,n) (((x) + (1 << ((n)-1))) >> (n))